# Delete list item if message is thrown

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a nested list with each element containing `FindRoot` like this:

```
{FindRoot[a,b], FindRoot[c,d], FindRoot[e,f],...}
```

Depending on the parameters `a,b,...`, the output looks like

```
{{1.25,-3.1},{0,-1.57},{6.28,1.},...}
```

Let's say the second invocation of `FindRoot` throws a message e.g. `The line search decreased the step size ...`, i.e. the result `{0,-1.57}` is incorrect and should not make it to the output - how can I do that?

```
DeleteCases[{FindRoot[a,b], FindRoot[c,d], FindRoot[e,f]},Except[{{_Real,_Real}...}]]
```

returns with an empty list, even when there is no error message.

Comment: `Check[FindRoot[a, b], Nothing]`?

Comment: @Carl: In your example, if `FindRoot` returns with an error message, `Check` returns with the string `Nothing`, which is what I would like to avoid altogther. Is there a way to not return anything (literally) in this case?

Comment: Nevermind.  The docs say "`Nothing` represents an element of a list that will *automatically* be removed."